# Getting username from tweets

Tags: python, twitter

On twitter I will find out few tweets on a particular keyword, then I want to generate the user name of the ID that tweeted the text.

How can I get the username or User Ids?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! This is not a code writing service, please review [ask] and show us what you've tried!

Answer (score 0):

This works, modify to suit your needs.

```
import twitter

keyword = 'python'
tweet_results = api.GetSearch(term=keyword,count=2)

for res in tweet_results:
    print 'User Id:{id}, username: {un}'.format(id=res.user.id, un=res.user.screen_name)
```

Prints:

```
User Id:20065936, username: mental_floss
User Id:16362921, username: developerWorks
```